# php - create large zip file blocks server

Tags: php, file, download, zip, large-files

I use the code bellow to create and download large zip file. Folders contain a very large number of files, about 20000 to 30000 files. The total file size is in the average of 2GB. This code works very well for small files but if it is the case of more than 10000 files, the server becomes unresponsive for several minutes.

```
<?php 

$folder= "../path/";

  header('Pragma: no-cache'); 
  header('Content-Description: File Download'); 
  header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="myZip.zip"');
  header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
  header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary'); 

   chdir( $folder );

    $fp = popen('zip -r -0 - ' . $folder, 'r');

  while(!feof($fp)) {
      echo fread($fp, 8192);
  } 
  //Closing the stream
    pclose($fp);
?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: You'll need to zip this in preparation before the download is actually initiated.  Preferably on a different server to the one serving HTTP requests.

Comment: i I have already tried this method, it didn't work.

Comment: To clarify, you have already tried streaming directly from a completed zip file as opposed to outputting the stdout of `zip`?  If thats so, could you please change your question example to reflect that attempt, because right now the current example isn't a good place to start from.